# Error in accessing RESTful api from angularjs

Tags: rest, angularjs, angularjs-service

I want to access to my services from RESTful API. I have added this code in angularJS. But it is returning failure always. I didn't understand why. Any help?

```
     $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:3000/profiles/someUser'}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
            alert("success")
            $scope.items = data;
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("failure")
        });
```

I have profiles/:username service in my RESTful API

Comment: can you specify the error please?

Comment: How do execute the JavaScript. From `localhost:3000` or a other URL (or even directly as a file)?

Comment: did you try this escape: http://localhost\\:3000/profiles ??? Also, you can call the url by ("profiles/:username") directly

Comment: Yes I tried that escape. But getting this error:        [21:26:32.101] GET http://localhost:3000/users/anil?callback=angular.callbacks._0 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 283ms]

Comment: I am executing this directly as a file. Should I change something here?

Comment: @anilCSE This should a access problem. JavaScript XHR request are not allowed to work across different domains (event same domains, but different ports). There might be even further restrictions when executing local JavaScript. To try serve everything from the same domain. (Or implements CORS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: Thank you. I tried by adding     app.use(allowCrossDomain);
in my app.config of RESTful service api, to implement CORS, but again same result. Is this a proper way?